# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on strncpy and array

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, upnp

I have a C file that I am calling in Objective-C for an iOS app. The C code does a UPNP discovery protocol and returns an array of all hosts found. When I execute the code from Objective-C I sometimes get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I sometimes don't. The main issue is in the code below (at the strncpy):

```
char *scanUPNP (int argc, char *argv[]) {
char **hostarray = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * MAX_NUM_HOSTS);

struct str_vector my_vector;

parse_cmd_opts(argc, argv);

str_vector_init(&my_vector);

discover_hosts(&my_vector, hostarray);

printf("\nHost Discovery Complete\n\n");

char* fatString = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)* MAX_NUM_HOSTS * 18);
int i = 0;
for (; i < MAX_NUM_HOSTS; i++) {
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
    if (hostarray[i] != NULL) {
        strncpy(tmp, hostarray[i], strlen(hostarray[i]));
        strncat(tmp, "\n", 1);
        strncat(fatString, tmp, strlen(tmp));
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
printf("IN C FOR UPNP: %s\n", fatString);

str_vector_free(&my_vector);

return fatString;
}
```

There are other resources on the site, but none of them seem to have a specific solution. Mainly just memory issues. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are sorely abusing both `strncpy` and `strncat`, and almost certainly overrunning your buffers. First, the `strncpy` is guaranteed to leave `tmp` unterminated, which means the following `strncat` won't work reliably. And in all three lines, the size passed as the third parameter should indicate how much space is available in the ***destination*** string, not how many characters are in the source string. For example, if `strlen(hostarray[i])` is 20, then the `strncpy` will overrun the `tmp` array.

Comment: Also, you allocate memory for `tmp` on every pass through the loop, and never `free` any of that memory. You be much better of just declaring `tmp` as `char tmp[100]` (even 100 may be a little small for some host names).

Comment: Thanks much @user3386109